# Android TextUtils

Tags: android

I can see that the TextUtils class has many functions that are identical in their purpose to functions found in the standard Java String class, such as indexOf. I'm wondering if they are aimed to just add more options to the developer, without any relation to the Android environment, such as calling indexOf on a CharSequence and not only on a String, or if they are supposed to actually replace the original functions due to issues they have when being used on Android.
Can someone please answer this informative question?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `TextUtils` is just a collection of useful methods and are not meant to replace methods from string class, just some methods from string and other methods which make your code smaller (see `TextUtils.isEmpty()` and `TextUtils.concat()`)

Comment: TextUtils methods are faster then traditional String methods on Android and therefore meant to replace them.

Comment: is it possible to check if the string is empty or null which the TextUtils class?